# Azure Data Lake Storage File Share File Path

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-files

I am not able to access any path in Azure file share folders. Everything I've tried is giving me an error "Operation: GETFILESTATUS failed with   Unknown Error: Name or service not known Name or service not known Source". Does this code look okay?

```
            var adlsClient = AdlsClient.CreateClient("myDataLakeAccount.azuredatalakestore.net", "Token");
            
            using MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            using StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);

            streamWriter.WriteLine("Testing file content to insert.");

            using var file = adlsClient.CreateFile("/Folder1/Folder2/Pending/TestFile.txt", IfExists.Overwrite);
            byte[] textByteArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
            file.Write(textByteArray, 0, textByteArray.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using below snippet of code to add a file in ADLS Gen2 container. You can use the below :

```
var storageAccountName = <YourStorageAccountName>;
var storageAccountKey = <YourStorageAccountKey>;
string serviceUri = "https://" + storageAccountName + ".dfs.core.windows.net";
var sampleFilePath = <YourLocalFilePath>;

StorageSharedKeyCredential sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(storageAccountName, storageAccountKey);

// Create DataLakeServiceClient using StorageSharedKeyCredentials

DataLakeServiceClient serviceClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(new Uri(serviceUri), sharedKeyCredential);

// Get a reference to a filesystem named "sample-filesystem-append" and then create it

DataLakeFileSystemClient filesystem = serviceClient.GetFileSystemClient("folder1");
filesystem.CreateIfNotExists();


DataLakeDirectoryClient directory = filesystem.GetDirectoryClient("/folder2/pending/");
directory.CreateIfNotExists();

DataLakeFileClient file = directory.GetFileClient("test1.txt");    
file.CreateIfNotExists();
var SampleFileContent = File.OpenRead(sampleFilePath);
file.Append(SampleFileContent, 0);
file.Flush(SampleFileContent.Length);
```

After executing the above code I could see the results in the ADLS Gen2 storage account

[image]

Date is written in the file

[image]

Refer [here](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/dotnet/Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake/12.0.0-preview.7/index.html)